# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar to int bigint

Tags: sql-server

Hopefully this is quite straight forward. I am trying to convert a column to int so I can sum on it.

```
SELECT (cast(RTRIM(pricing_prices)as int)) FROM returnxx where RMAid= '5'
```

**errors**

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value
>   '9.8000000000000007' to data type int.

If I try bigint I get another error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

Comment: Try using `FLOOR` instead.

Comment: SELECT TRY_CONVERT(INT, pricing_prices) FROM returnxx where RMAid= '5'  returns 'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: `INT` and `BIGINT` are whole numbers, you should look at `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` if you want to keep decimal places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert into `Numeric` and then `INT`.
Try this:

```
DECLARE @Var varchar(100)='9.8000000000000007' 
SELECT CAST(CAST(@Var AS NUMERIC(35,16)) AS INT)
```

**Result:**

```
9
```

If you want `ROUND` value, just convert into Numeric:

```
SELECT CAST(@Var AS NUMERIC)
```

**Result:**

```
10
```

If you want `DECIMAL` value, just convert into Numeric:

```
SELECT CAST(@Var AS NUMERIC(8,2))
```

**Result:**

```
9.80
```

Comment: I need it rounded to 2 decimals as its a price.

Comment: @Emma You need **9.80**, Right?

Comment: @Emma, You are Welcome..!

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem in the past. i was able to resolve it by casting the column to decimal first then cast it to an Integer. You can cast it to any decimal of your choice

```
DECLARE @pricing_prices NVARCHAR(20)='9.8000000000000007' AS pricing_prices

SELECT  CAST(CAST(@pricing_prices AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS INT)
```

Output

```
pricing_prices
9
```